# Can I disable HTTPS on a specific path only, using jwilder/nginx-proxy?

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have a web app reverse-proxied through jwilder/nginx-proxy, which applies my TLS certificate. There is one path served by this app that I want to either have TLS disabled, or at least optional if `http://` is specified.

Using custom configuration, virtual host specific configs, or anything short of editing the template... is there a way to do this?

I have tried:

1. Setting the target container as `HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect`. (But this makes HTTP possible on all paths, obviously.)
2. Put a location config in *e.g.* `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/app.example.com` but these config files seem to get added to the server section listening to port 443. So that does not help.
3. Tried combining the two above, but adding a location like:

```
    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

(But that leads to nginx complaining that there are duplicate locations.)

Comment: Would it be possible to use a different hostname, i.e. `secure-api.example.com` and `api.example.com`?  That may bring in CORS issues if you're also doing UI stuff but it would allow you to separate the SSL vs non-SSL areas.

Comment: I would prefer not to, but I am negotiable here...  I don't think CORS would be an issue, as the path I am concerned with is "just" backend data shuffling around.